# How can I get views_save_view($view) to return TRUE when using Drush?

Tags: views, drush

I have a script that calls various views API functions, namely views_save_view() or $view->save().

When using Drush 5 to run the script, these functions return false. However, when I run these with cron while logged into Drupal through the config, it works fine and everything executes as normal.

How can I get these to return true while using Drush?

I have feeling this is a permissions issue, but can't figure out how to get Drush to execute with the permissions it needs. This is a follow up question to here:

[How can I run Drush as user 1 in version 5?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64231/how-can-i-run-drush-as-user-1-in-version-5/)

Also there is a somewhat related issue here:

http://drupal.org/node/1515616#comment-6312604

Comment: note: This is not just happening with views_save_view(). It's also happening with views_get_view(). I even tried to write a separate script and execute it with drush php-script rather than having the code in cron in a module (was calling drush cron). Nothing will save; views_get_view() returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script as a user with the right command line option. Basically:

`drush php-script YOURSCRIPTNAME.php --user=1`

or `--user=UID` where UID is a valid drupal user ...

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. For whatever reason, I cannot get views functions to work correctly with Drush even with the user changed. Thoughts?